# Issue with fetching number value from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function :

```
  final ref= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('test').doc('t');

  Future _custom()async{
    await ref.update({'t':FieldValue.increment(1)});
    await ref.get().then((last) => print(last.data()!['t']));
    return;
  }
```

With a button `onPressed` method, I called the function continuously many times.
I expect result be like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But, I got this:

```
1
1
3
3
4
4
7
```

While I made the clicks much faster, the result goes **terribly wrong**. But, when get slower it comes more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `FieldValue.increment(x)` will ensure that there are no overlapping write conflicts, the method in which you read the number out will give you false results.

If you check your data after all the increments you will see that it is correct.

If you wanna ensure that your user gets the right number displayed you can increment your local application state on click, kind of like a optimistic write.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#dart_12

> Warning. Increment operations are useful for implementing counters,
> but keep in mind that you can update a single document only once per
> second.

Comment: Distributed counter extension would be the final solution for the issue. I think.

Answer (score 0):

You simply replace by this
`await ref.set({'t':FieldValue.increment(1)},isMerged:true);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).